Smoothing functions in perlin noise
I am trying to make an animated perlin noise simulation in js but got stuck on some problems with the smoothing functions.
Here is my js code (I have removed some irrelevant code for easier reading)
The code makes a box with n-grid with n-blocks insides. Each grid have four vectors. The calculate functions calculates the dot product for each block with the four vectors of the grid the block is in.

var GRIDSIZE = 0;
const VECTOR_COUNT = 3;
const DETAIL = 50;
const MARGIN = 100;

var FADE = .5;

const MAX_ROTATIONSPEED = 0.03;
const MIN_ROTATIONSPEED = -MAX_ROTATIONSPEED;

var vectorList = [];
var BLOCK_LIST = [];
var blockList = [];

// Set up main grid
mainEl.style.width = GRIDSIZE + "px";
mainEl.style.height = GRIDSIZE + "px";
mainEl.style.position = "absolute";
mainEl.style.left = window.innerWidth / 2 - mainEl.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
mainEl.style.top = window.innerHeight / 2 - mainEl.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";
if(window.innerHeight - MARGIN > window.innerWidth - MARGIN) {
  GRIDSIZE = window.innerWidth - MARGIN;
} else {
  GRIDSIZE = window.innerHeight - MARGIN;
}
mainEl.style.width = GRIDSIZE + "px";
mainEl.style.height = GRIDSIZE + "px";
mainEl.style.left = window.innerWidth / 2 - mainEl.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
mainEl.style.top = window.innerHeight / 2 - mainEl.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";


// functions
var DOT = (angle, x, y) => x * Math.cos(angle) + y * Math.sin(angle);
var lerp = (a, b, t) => a + (b - a) * t;
var fade = (t) => t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
var normalize = (value, max, min) => (value - min) / (max - min);
var hypotenuse = (x, y) => Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);





// Setup
setUpVectors();
setUpBlocks();
// console.log(BLOCK_LIST);

var calculate = () => {
  var VECTOR_GRID = [];
  vectorList.forEach((vector, i) => {
    if(i % VECTOR_COUNT < VECTOR_COUNT-1 && Math.floor(i / VECTOR_COUNT) < VECTOR_COUNT-1) {
      var v0 = vector;
      var v1 = vectorList[i+1];
      var v2 = vectorList[i+VECTOR_COUNT];
      var v3 = vectorList[i+VECTOR_COUNT+1];
      
      var trueV0 = {
        x: v0.tipX / Math.sqrt(v0.tipX*v0.tipX + v0.tipY*v0.tipY),
        y: v0.tipY / Math.sqrt(v0.tipX*v0.tipX + v0.tipY*v0.tipY),
        angle: v0.angle
      }
      var trueV1 = {
        x: v1.tipX / Math.sqrt(v1.tipX*v1.tipX + v1.tipY*v1.tipY),
        y: v1.tipY / Math.sqrt(v1.tipX*v1.tipX + v1.tipY*v1.tipY),
        angle: v1.angle
      }
      var trueV2 = {
        x: v2.tipX / Math.sqrt(v2.tipX*v2.tipX + v2.tipY*v2.tipY),
        y: v2.tipY / Math.sqrt(v2.tipX*v2.tipX + v2.tipY*v2.tipY),
        angle: v2.angle
      }
      var trueV3 = {
        x: v3.tipX / Math.sqrt(v3.tipX*v3.tipX + v3.tipY*v3.tipY),
        y: v3.tipY / Math.sqrt(v3.tipX*v3.tipX + v3.tipY*v3.tipY),
        angle: v3.angle
      }
      VECTOR_GRID.push([trueV0, trueV1, trueV2, trueV3]);
      // console.log(trueV0, trueV1, trueV2, trueV3);
    }
  });

  var state = 0;
  var dotList0 = []; //dot product for each blocks top left corner
  var dotList1 = []; //dot product for each blocks top right corner
  var dotList2 = []; //dot product for each blocks bottom left corner
  var dotList3 = []; //dot product for each blocks bottom right corner
  var DOT_LIST = [];

  var state = 0;
  VECTOR_GRID.forEach((vector, i) => {
    vector.forEach((v, j) => {
      for(var k = 0; k < BLOCK_LIST[i].length; k++) {
        if(j === 0) {
          var x = BLOCK_LIST[0][k].senterX * (GRIDSIZE/100)
          var y = BLOCK_LIST[0][k].senterY * (GRIDSIZE/100)
          var trueB = {
            x: x / hypotenuse(x, y),
            y: y / hypotenuse(x, y)
          }
          dotList0.push(DOT(vector[j].angle, trueB.x, trueB.y));
        } else if(j === 1) {
          var x = GRIDSIZE/(VECTOR_COUNT-1) - BLOCK_LIST[0][k].senterX * (GRIDSIZE/100)
          var y = BLOCK_LIST[0][k].senterY * (GRIDSIZE/100)
          // console.log(x, y);
          var trueB = {
            x: -x / hypotenuse(x, y),
            y: y / hypotenuse(x, y)
          }
          dotList1.push(DOT(vector[j].angle, trueB.x, trueB.y));          
        } else if(j === 2) {
          var x = BLOCK_LIST[0][k].senterX * (GRIDSIZE/100)
          var y = GRIDSIZE/(VECTOR_COUNT-1) - BLOCK_LIST[0][k].senterY * (GRIDSIZE/100)
          var trueB = {
            x: x / hypotenuse(x, y),
            y: -y / hypotenuse(x, y)
          }
          dotList2.push(DOT(vector[j].angle, trueB.x, trueB.y));
        } else if(j === 3) {
          var x = GRIDSIZE/(VECTOR_COUNT-1) - BLOCK_LIST[0][k].senterX * (GRIDSIZE/100)
          var y = GRIDSIZE/(VECTOR_COUNT-1) - BLOCK_LIST[0][k].senterY * (GRIDSIZE/100)
          var trueB = {
            x: -x / hypotenuse(x, y),
            y: -y / hypotenuse(x, y)
          }
          dotList3.push(DOT(vector[j].angle, trueB.x, trueB.y));
        }
      }
    });
  });


  var DOT_LIST = [dotList0, dotList1, dotList2, dotList3];

  var colorList = [];
  
  for (var k = 0; k < DOT_LIST[0].length; k++) {
    var dot01 = lerp(DOT_LIST[0][k], DOT_LIST[1][k], fade(FADE));
    var dot23 = lerp(DOT_LIST[2][k], DOT_LIST[3][k], fade(FADE));
    var dot0123 = lerp(dot01, dot23, fade(FADE));
    // console.log(dot0123);
    var color = Math.floor(normalize(dot0123, 1, -1) * 255);
    colorList.push(color);
  }

  ALL_BLOCKS.forEach((block, i) => {
    block.block.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${colorList[i]},${colorList[i]},${colorList[i]})`;
  });
};

function animate() {
  updateVectors();
  updateMainEl();
  calculate();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();

Right now each grid makes a believable gradient, but the grid should be "connected" with each other, and it does not do that. I suspect I my fade functions that do not work.

NOTE: JS has a built-in Math.hypot function.

You may want to implement simplex noise instead (also by Perlin, but does not have directional artifacting)
